# JQuery Library error ? Drag and Drop event triggered only by handle content

Tags: javascript, jquery

watch the [video](http://screencast.com/t/hscVENHju) first;

As seen in the video I try to drag and drop a element;

This is a widget, a DnD capable element;

```
<div class="well dragbox" id="dragbox_<?php echo $id; ?>" style="z-index: <?php echo $zid; ?>; left: <?php echo $dbview->left; ?>px; top: <?php echo $dbview->top; ?>px; width: <?php echo $dbview->width; ?>px; height: <?php echo $dbview->height + 18; ?>px; padding-bottom: 18px;">
            <div class='header' style="display:block;">
                <?php
                echo CHtml::link('', array("/user/dbview/delete/id/$id"), array('style' => 'float: right; margin-left: 10px; display:block;', 'class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'), 'Are you sure you want to remove this widget?');
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php echo $code; ?>
        </div>
```

this is the code for it:

```
    $(".dragbox").draggable({
        handle: ".header",
        grid: [1, 1],
        containment: 'parent',
        reflow: true,
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            //do not update the widgets pos/size not even by accident when we are in forced rearrange mode
            if (jQuery('#widget_content').hasClass('floating-dashboard-widgets'))
                return false;
            var id = ui.helper.context.id.split('_')[1];
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/user/dbview/update/id/'; ?>" + id,
                data: {data: {left: ui.position.left, top: ui.position.top, parent_width: get_parent_width(), parent_height: get_parent_height()}},
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.status == 'true') {
                    }
                },
                dataType: 'json',
            });
        }
    });
```

the `header` is a div that has a link within, with a hover effect;

a DnD element will always move if I click on the right top link and start to drag it, no mather what browser I use;

I used Chrome and IE9 in this case;

if I try to DnD a element by using the div.header element as the handle, it fails;

the Drag and Drop event triggered only by handle content, by the X right top link;

How to fix this?